# How do I run antlr4 on a Java file in the commandline?

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm trying to use antlr to get the AST of a given java file. I've run antlr4 on both the JavaLexer.g4 and the JavaParser.g4 to generate everything but I'm trying to use grun to see the tree from a java file. I've tried commands like this  `.\grun JavaLexer tokens HelloWorld.java -gui` but get nothing back.

I'm confused on if I need to be calling the JavaLexer, the JavaParser or if I completely have the command wrong in every way.
I'm using PowerShell if that matters.

(edit) the correct powershell command is: `.\grun Java compilationUnit HelloWorld.java -gui` Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.\grun Java compilationUnit -gui < HellowWorld.java
```

(not positive re: the syntax of piping HellowWorld.java to lysin in PowerShell)

grun wants the grammarName (`Java` in your case), then the start rule (`compilationUnit` for the Java Parser if you want to parse a *.java source file)

Referencing the Lexer grammar name and using `tokens` as the "start rule" is a special case that only works with the -tokens options to tokenize the input stream and dump the tokens.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, unfortunately I get an exception when I run a command like that. `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class JavaParser
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3924)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.process(TestRig.java:135)
        at org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig.main(TestRig.java:119)`

Comment: Sorry about that.  The TestRig program appends "Parser" to the `grammarName` when it tries to load the Parser class, so you should use `Java` as the `grammarName`